# como retornar un valor de 4 cifras (ni mas ni menos) y que retorne con sus cifras invertidas en python

Tags: python

Amigos ayudenme con esta pregunta que me dejaron en un taller, en verdad he intentado pero no me da, he intentado esto:

```
def invertida(n):

    """
    problema: recibir un numero de 4 cifras y devolver sus cifras invertidas

    entrada: numero

    salida: numero invertido
    """

    numero = (n[::-1])
    return numero 

invertida(1234)
```

pero eso de `[::-1]` no me da y me gustaria que la persona pueda introducir exactamente 4 digitos, ni mas ni menos, pero no se como :(

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo porque dices que no te funciona, con este simple ejemplo te debería funcionar a la perfección validando que el número sea de 4 digitos

```
input = raw_input('Escriba un número de 4 digitos: ')
if len(input) == 4:
  print(input[::-1])
else:
  print("Error, el número debe ser de 4 digitos")
```

Te dejo [aquí](https://repl.it/FhEu) un ejemplo funcional del código anterior

**EDIT 1**: No había visto que lo querías dentro de una función pero siendo así, esto te debería servir

```
def cadenaInvertida(n):

  if len(str(n)) == 4:
    return str(n)[::-1]
  else:
    return False

print(cadenaInvertida(1234))
```

Te dejo [aquí](https://repl.it/FhEu/1) un ejemplo funcional del código anterior

Lo que pasa es que la función está leyendo un número como tal y a este no se le puede aplicar dicho código para invertirlo, por lo que debes pasarlo primero a una variable de tipo `str`